# Conda command comes with invalid syntax error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have just downloaded Anaconda 3.7 (Windows 7, 64-bit) and when I try to do anything using "conda" it just says that "conda is not recognized as an internal or external command". I put Anaconda folder to my path but yet nothing happens. In addition, when I try to import numpy it appears a message stating "Import Error: DLL load failed: Specified
module can´t be found". On another pc, when I have Anaconda 3.6 (Windows 8, 64-bit) everything works fine, so is it just a problem of 3.7 version? Any ideas on how to come after this error?

Comment: Are you trying to run the conda commands from windows command prompt, powershell, anaconda prompt, etc.?

Comment: Hi, G.Anderson! I have tried to run it from the anaconda prompt in the first place and since it did not work I tried to do it from windows command prompt after moving to the Anaconda directory. Didn't work either !